# Is possible to have multiple global IPs running on the same server?

Tags: python, api, server, ip

I'm currently working on a python code that manages multiple user accounts and accesses the provider's API, instantiates a websocket and makes action requests, but it has a limit of requests per account and per IP, the quota of accounts is never reached, but the quota of request by IP is being reached easily and I'm being blocked from making a request from time to time, the question is if I can have more than one IP per server so I don't have this quota problem.

Already tried to instanse different VPS, but some profiders have the same IP for cheap VPS. (the client manager is very ligth in processing, if i have to instance a lot of VPS just for diffent IPs, i ended up using 2-5% of each VPS)

I´m new to network in general, sorry if it´s already been responded somewhere else (didn´t find anywhere) or is to much of a newbie question..

Comment: _more than one IP per server_: Technically yes, but that's provider related, if they offer you more IPs usable with a cheap VPS.

Comment: Even if you can have multiple IPs, API libraries may not provide a way for you to select a specific IP for your connection.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer, i´ll look into it, probably get in touch with my internet provider if multiples ips is a possibility

Comment: @Barmar i can run multiple "small" servers simultaneously, each responsible just to make the request, so that´s not a big problem

Comment: You could do it using virtual machines, each with their own IP.